# How to assert id which changes with successive registered user using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am writing selenium webdriver code using c#. I have a registration page where on clicking submit button, a text is shown at the top "Successfully registered with new user having ID as id"

This 'id' changes every time I register a new user like for the first user, its 1, for second, its 2.

I need to assert like on submitting the form this text shown above is present on the same page. Is there any way I can increment the id and assert it for successful registration.

```
IWebElement q1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSave"));
        Boolean a1 = q1.Displayed;
        Assert.True(a1, "Element not present");
        q1.Click();
        Assert.AreEqual("Success! Successfully saved with id: 424", driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='wdf_root_div_id']/div[4]")).Text);
```

This '424' id changes everytime. So how to go ahead?

Comment: can you show the html after the id is displayed on page?

Comment: You should show us a snippet of the HTML that this is being run against and a snippet of the code you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not bothered about the ID and just want to check the "Success! Successfully saved with id:"

```
if(Driver.getPageSource().contains("Success! Successfully saved with id:")){
 //Your page has the text.. 
 //This is Java you need to convert to C#
}
```

Comment: This text is not present in the page source. May be its hidden don't know why.